# jquery - target only current element no parent

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add border only to the element where my mouse is, but my code is add border to its parent element as well,

**My code:**

```
jQuery('body').mousemove(function(e){   
var el = e.target;
        jQuery(el).hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).css('outline','solid 2px #000');
        },function(){
            jQuery(this).css('outline','');
        });
});
```

Fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/howtoplease/gk8t7/**

Comment: Why are you binding the `hover` event *inside* the `mousemove` event?

Comment: I m not a javascript expert, just checking if it work or not :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is the use of `.hover`. `.hover` uses the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. `mouseleave` won't trigger on a parent element when you enter the child element, therefore the outline will stay till you "leave" the parent and all children. Additionally, you need to prevent a `mouseover` on the child from propagating to a parent.

```
//jQuery('body').mousemove(function(e){ 
    //var el = e.target;
    jQuery('div').mouseover(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).css('outline', 'solid 2px #000');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        jQuery(this).css('outline', '');
    });
//});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk8t7/9/

also, i don't quite understand why you are using the `body` `mousemove`, is this a debugging tool where you won't know which elements you want it defined on?

Comment: actually it is not body, in my code i m doing mousemove on a div

Comment: The problem is, every time the mouse is moved, another event is being bound to said elements. It would be better to just bind to them directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very simply. Add a class name to all elements (in this case I am just using 'div' since there are only divs) that should get the outline and add the following event listener to your js.

```
jQuery('div').mousemove(function (e) {
    $el = $(e.target)
    $('div').removeClass('outline')
    $el.addClass('outline')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk8t7/12/

Answer (score 2):

Use the [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method of jQuery if you don't want to use classes.

```
$('div').hover(function(e){ 
    $(this).parents().css('outline','');
    jQuery(this).css('outline','solid 2px #000');
},function(){
    $(this).parent('div').css('outline','solid 2px #000');
    jQuery(this).css('outline','');
});
```

If you mouse out, you are already on the parent element actually and you never moused out of it, so you find the parent div wrapping the `$(this)` using [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and giving it border to simulate.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gk8t7/13/

Comment: Right, but now it doesn't add the outline to the parent as you move the mouse back out.

Comment: That can be fixed easily, updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

To not let it effect the parent elements.

Comment: add e.stopPropagation(); under mousemove or hover ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to change the outline, otherwise you never know where to remove the outline from:

```
jQuery('body').mousemove(function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    $('.outline').removeClass('outline'); //remove outline
    jQuery(el).addClass('outline'); // add outline
});
```

CSS:

```
.outline {
    outline: solid 2px #000;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/UQhVE/

Comment: Dear neal I am not looking for css class solution. Anyway thanks for the solution

Comment: @HowToPlease Why not? How else would you do it?

Comment: @HowToPlease Can you explain?

Comment: I am trying highlight DOM, as firebug do, then edit selected element's css. +1 for you anser

Comment: @HowToPlease so your **do** want to edit the CSS. So what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I want to highlight current target element, and then wan to add a overlay and then if it get clicked then open a div which `attr` current target style... No problem with your answer, it works

Comment: @HowToPlease you still did not explain why CSS does not work?

Comment: Dear neal I am trying to select only current element not parent using jQuery

Comment: @HowToPlease You **are** selecting the current element with `e.target`, your issue is that you are not unoutlining the one that your previously selected, which is much easier to do with a CSS selector.

Comment: @dievardump that too.